# How to add params to url of http requests in ktor client

Tags: android, ktor-client

I am having issues adding url params to my http requests with ktor client.

in my nodeJS backend I am expecting urls with a path variable in the url like this:

```
// plants.route.ts
this.router.delete('/plants/delete/:id', this.plantsController.delete);
```

I am following the ktor client documentation to add params to my http request url as described here: https://ktor.io/docs/request.html
So my code now looks like this:

```
// HttpRoutes.kt
const val deletePlantRoute = "$backendUrl/plants/delete"

// PlantApiImplementation.kt
override suspend fun deletePlant(plantId: String): DeletePlantResponseDTO? {
  return try {
    client.delete {
      url(HttpRoutes.deletePlantRoute)
      parameter("id", plantId)
      contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
    }
  } catch (error: Exception) {
    return null
  }
}
```

But the requests are not reaching my backend.

So far I have tried solutions from the following SO threads:

[Example of URL builder in Ktor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64430757/example-of-url-builder-in-ktor)

[How to pass query parameters to Ktor android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71523698/how-to-pass-query-parameters-to-ktor-android)

Answer (score 1):

So after doing some digging and rewatching a youtube tutorial about ktor client i realized i was confusing `query` parameters in the documentation with `path` parameters.

https://youtu.be/3KTXD_ckAX0?t=683

What worked in the end was simply building the url directly in my api call like this:

```
// PlantApiImplementation.kt
override suspend fun deletePlant(plantId: String): DeletePlantResponseDTO? {
  return try {
    client.delete {
      // build the url directly with the needed params here
      url(HttpRoutes.deletePlantRoute + "/" + plantId)
      contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
    }
  } catch (error: Exception) {
    return null
  }
}
```